# Approch at leading an Element through the page while Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to "lead" respectively move an Element (the red one in the sketch below) through the page in a given way (so it won't collide with the content). The box should move along the given path while the user is scrolling.

I tried to set the position of the element to fixed at the left / top corner and then just move it along the horizontal axis while scrolling. But i think this is not the best solution and the code is pretty ugly.

I also tried to solve this with the skrollr parallax framework, but this isn't possible.

Here is a sketch of what i'm trying to achieve:
[image]

So what is the best approach to solve this?

**Edit:**
To get a better idea of what i'm trying to achieve here's a link to a page which has something similar: http://rit-team.ru/

Answer (score 2):

That page is unbelievably cool...

If you want to preset the path (as they did) then the principal is pretty straight forward. Define an array of 'checkpoints', essentially x coordinates. You then use the vertical scroll offset as an index into that array, setting the position of your moving element accordingly.

If you want to 'drive around' elements of arbitrary size, then I have no idea. These guys won a design award for their efforts, so I'm guessing it's not a walk in the park.